# Помощь с moment js

Tags: javascript, jquery, unix, momentjs

Не могу разобраться, помогите
Есть время в секундах unix
Условно 1651821577
Fri, 06 May 2022 07:19:37 GMT
На момент написания поста, это время наступит через +- 24 часа.

Как мне вывести в js что-то типа "событие наступит через 1 день 1 час 1 минуту 1 секунду".
Чтобы показывались дни, часы, минуты, секунды.

Answer (score 1):

Больше информации про методы можно посмотреть в [документации библиотеки](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/diffing/).

```js
const timeUnix = 1651821577;

const time = moment.unix(timeUnix);
const nowTime = moment();

const duration = moment.duration(time.diff(nowTime));

console.log(`day: ${duration.days()}, hours: ${duration.hours()}, minutes: ${duration.minutes()}, seconds: ${duration.seconds()}`)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: И хорошо бы подсказать, что ответы на этот и другие вопросы можно найти в [документации](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/diffing/). Документация -- друг разработчика.